# using awk to to find and replace string with calculation based on the string

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a 3-column file of the form

```
 5565 35824 58.8 
 5713 67404 94.1 
 5716 64456 94.1 
 5718 60492 94.1
 5724 57588 88.2
 5718 844188 75.0
 5757 903388 75.0 
 5724 871828 68.8
 5565 1.0g 43.8
 5565 1.3g 37.5
 5718 878060 6.2
```

The middle column is memory in KB (from RSS column of `top` command).

I want to convert the entries expressed in GB (e.g. `1.0g`) to the equivalent number in KB, or `1.0g` to `1000000`. I'm not sure how to use `awk` to find and replace those entries with the equivalent calculated values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following `awk` command should do:

```
awk 'sub(/g$/,"",$2) {$2=1000000*$2}1' input.txt
```

This will check if the second column (`$2`) ends in a lower-case `g`, by attempting to substitute a trailing `g` with "nothing" (thereby reducing the field to the numerical value only). If that succeeds (i.e. the return value of `sub()`, which is the number of successful substitutions performed, is non-zero), it multiplies the field value by 1000000.

The trailing `1` instructs `awk` to print all lines, including any modifications made.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works!. One further question is how the multiplication only includes the numeric value of the field and does not include the g? Any recommendation for awk references where I might have figured this out myself?

Comment: @EdHall In that case, I must admit it is simply because "my experience tells" - I didn't find any reference for this on short notice (and it might mean that it is not portable to all `awk` implementations, although it works on all I have tried so far). I think I wil include a small modification to make the code "cleaner". Btw, if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.